# Lazarus Android Module Wizard in Free Pascal

Tags: android, android-studio, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

When I tried to rebuild Lazarus (because is a requirement if you want to have the LAMW COMPONENTS), I got this error

`can't open object file ldResourceStringsOpenSSL.o`

and this error

`can't open object file ldResourceStringsSSPI.o`

How can I fix this?
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwf7f.jpg]

Comment: Without trying to be a jerk here-  have you considered using a modern language?  Pascal hasn't been anything but a teaching language in 40 years, and really even that ended 30 years ago.  The standard languages for Android development are  Kotlin and Java, with a smattering of Javascript, Dart, C++ and C#.  Pascal isn't in the top 50.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, How about Delphi? Its the only programing language I use and very powerful. And it's basically Pascal.

Comment: @ErrorInCode Delphi hasn't been a major language... I want to be snarky and say ever, but at least not in a long while.  And using it on Android is even a smaller usecase.  You're of course free to use what you want, but when you want to use such niche languages you're going to put in a lot of time figuring stuff out and fixing things, because you may be one of only dozens or hundreds of people worldwide to be doing it.

Comment: @GabeSechan, quite interesting. I suppose I never checked that much into that, I just used the language I learned in.

Comment: @ErrorInCode The good news is that programming languages in the end have a lot of the same concepts.  So learning a second is easier than the first.  And it exposes you to new ways of thinking, so you tend to be better at both of them afterwards.

Comment: Lazarus / FPC is an awesome development environment if you care to have a proper look at it. Especially useful for developers that are not rich and have legacy Delphi code or for very rapid development for any target OS.